# how to add OAuth redirect URI through facebook graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0

In my facebook app , I have added Facebook login as the Product. To add a redirect URI, I can go to developer.facebook.com -> my app -> Products -> Facebook Login and I can add URL and save changes.

However, My requirement is to add it through API as the redirect uri is known while running the test case (changes each time test runs). Is this exposed through graph API?

Comment: No, it is not. You can not set that field via API.